# SQL Task help pls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions

I attached an image of a simple task I got and I would love your help to see If I got it right.

[image: my-task]

My answer:

```sql
SELECT 
    Account_name, 
    SUM(captcha_served) AS Total_captcha_served,
    SUM(captcha_solved) AS Total_captcha_solved
FROM 
    DEFENDIT_pageviews_20190101
WHERE
    Account_name = "defendit";
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Attempting to run your SQL will tell you if you got it right or not though; why do you need us to tell you, when you can far more easily readily test?

Comment: just add group by Account_name as well in query

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't ask a question other than for us to test the SQL in the question to see if it "works". This is something the OP can easily do, by simply running the statement, while the users here are unable to do so as we do not have access to the user's instance nor do we have sample data (an image does not count, as that expects us to transcribe it, which we should be be expected to do). If the above isn't working, then they should be asking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is missing a `group by` clause:

```
select account_name, 
    sum(captcha_served) as total_captcha_served, 
    sum(captcha_solved) as total_captcha_solved 
from defendit_pageviews_20190101 
where account_name = 'defendit'
group by account_name  --> here
```

I would also recommend using single quotes rather than double quotes to surround literal strings. This is standard SQL, that all databases support.